# restoration of deleted data by mistake

Tags: hotmail

i wanted to delete the data using the service however i deleted the data from my own phone by mistake. complete data from device as well as SD card have been erased.

Please assist to restore same.

Thanks & Best regards,
-Anand

Comment: unfortunately there is no backup taken in google drive as well.

Comment: Data was deleted using " https://myaccount.google.com/device-activity "

Answer (score 0):

I'd try pulling the SD card and doing a few attempts at data recovery from it.  If it's been formatted as EXT3/4 I'd try using Photorec on a Linux system.  If it's anything else I'd try GetDataBack or FreeUndelete on Windows.

I know of no way to attempt that on the device's internal storage, sorry.

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for your suggestion. I hooked my SD card through card reader and managed to recover 80% of data using "iCare Data Recovery Free" software. Thanks for saving my useful docs. :)

Comment: @AnandRana Awesome, glad it helped!